# Installing oracle java versions

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk, oracle

I went to the website to download (**Java Platform (JDK) 8u20** ),

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

to download ORACLE java for my machine. I was confused which packages are necessary for me.

the command `uname -a` shows

```
Linux xxx 3.13.0-35-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:42 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Please suggest me what are the packages I should download and install for oracle java.

Answer (score 2):

You need the `jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz` package. Unpack it somewhere (`/usr/share` for instance), it is ready to work.

But you can experience some conflicts with OpenJDK which is most probably already installed on your computer. If you want to make sure a jar file is executed with Oracle java, start it from the command line using java full path:

```
/usr/share/jdk-8u20-linux-x64/bin/java -jar a_jarexecutable.jar
```

Hope this helps